# Oracle - Index use with optional parameters

Tags: oracle, database-indexes

I use the following trick to be able to index a column that has some nulls:

```
create index xx_people_idx1 on xx_people(id_number, -1);
```

This works great. Sadly this does not help for when you use optional parameters though:

```
select *
from xx_people
where id_number = nvl(:p_id_number, id_number);
```

This results in a full table scan, even when you provide a value for `p_id_number`. Is there a trick to use the index in this situation?

Since searching by id number and name are my only 2 searches this is very desirable.

Comment: [Use a function-based index](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_indexes.htm#ADFNS00505). Best of luck.

Comment: How would I write the function based index to work with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NVL` trick ought to work and allow index access.  In fact, `NVL` is generally the best way to do this, and usually works better than other conditions involving `CASE` or `OR`.  I've used the `NVL` trick many times and the simple test case below shows that it can use an index.

### Schema

```
create table xx_people(id_number number, a number, b number);

insert into xx_people
select level, level, level from dual connect by level <= 100000;

commit;

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'xx_people');
end;
/

create index xx_people_idx1 on xx_people(id_number, -1);
```

### Generate Execution Plan

```
explain plan for
select *
from xx_people
where id_number = nvl(:p_id_number, id_number);

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

### Execution Plan

```
Plan hash value: 3301250992

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                 |   100K|  3808K|   106   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  VIEW                                  | VW_ORE_67373E14 |   100K|  3808K|   106   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL                            |                 |       |       |            |          |
|*  3 |    FILTER                              |                 |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| XX_PEOPLE       |     1 |    15 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | XX_PEOPLE_IDX1  |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |    FILTER                              |                 |       |       |            |          |
|*  7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | XX_PEOPLE       |   100K|  1464K|   103   (1)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter(:P_ID_NUMBER IS NOT NULL)
   5 - access("ID_NUMBER"=:P_ID_NUMBER)
   6 - filter(:P_ID_NUMBER IS NULL)
   7 - filter("ID_NUMBER" IS NOT NULL)
```

That plan is a bit confusing at first.  But it's got the best of both worlds; the filter operation allows Oracle to decide at run time to use a full table scan when the bind variable is null (and all rows are returned), and an index when the bind variable is not null (and only a few rows are returned).

This all means that there is probably something weird happening in your specific case.  You may need to post a fully reproducible test case for us to figure out why an index isn't used.