# Oracle SQL placeholder for everything in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a SQL query with a `WHERE` clause that does not actually filter anything.

```
import cx_Oracle
condition = []
#condition = ['a', 'b']

query = ("""
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE var = {}""".format(tuple(condition)))

with cx_Oracle.connect(dsn=tsn), encoding="UTF-8")) as con:
    df = pd.read_sql(con=con, sql=query)
```

Disclaimer: Still a bit new to SQL. I appreciate corrections of terminology

Edit:

Answer (score 2):

This is often handled using logic like this:

```
where col = :input_val or :input_val is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have the WHERE clause filter anything then it needs to contain a condition which is always true; something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
  WHERE var = var OR
        var IS NULL
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=deaa0e8b633c5a78649e1e6c6bdde00f)

Comment: Well, if you don't want the WHERE clause to filter anything, then you don't need the WHERE clause at all. Do you?

Comment: @Littlefoot: agreed, but OP specifically said he wanted a WHERE clause so I didn't include the option to *not* have a WHERE clause.

Comment: I apologize, Bob. Honestly, I didn't read what the OP said but looked at what *you* said and ... well, posted that stupid comment. Anyway, I prefer what @Gordon wrote, it is more clear than `var = var`.

Comment: No offense taken, no apology necessary.

Comment: Thank you, I really didn't mean to offend you, but - apology was necessary. Should be more careful, I know.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use an index and the column value is not nullable then you'll want to use the `NVL` trick. I don't know why, but Oracle has better optimizations for `NVL` than for the `...OR A IS NULL` expression.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE nvl(anyvalueofvar1, var) = var;
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49397371/409172) for an example of the better execution plan generated by this different syntax.

(I said "and the column value is not nullable" because `NULL = NULL` is not true in Oracle, so the `NVL` expression won't work if the column has nulls. I usually hate these cryptic syntaxes with weird behavior, but they are sometimes necessary for performance.)